# clinfo hangs when using fglrx-core on Kaveri

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amd-catalyst, opencl, fglrx

I've had a working installation with OpenCL running and unfortunately executed dist-upgrade on my Ubuntu (because of the glibc bug). Then I recognized that OpenCL was not working anymore.I re-installed `fglrx-core` and tried to execute `clinfo`. Curiously, it runs endlessly with a CPU usage of 100%. Additionally, I cannot kill it with `SIGKILL` (kernel mode?).

Here is my system specification and some driver infos:

- `Kaveri [Radeon R7 Graphics] APU`
- `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Linux ***** 3.13.0-77-generic #121-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 20 10:50:42 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux).`
- `fglrx-core/trusty-updates,now 2:15.200-0ubuntu0.6 amd64 [installed]`

I ran `strace clinfo` on the broken system and an equivalent one (same configuration, but still working). Here is the [broken version](http://pastebin.com/chgSXriR) and the [working one](http://pastebin.com/LDCAXXPD).

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In the broken version's strace, folder /etc/ati and various files inside that folder do not exist. clinfo is known to crash if /etc/ati is not present. You can try to copy folder /etc/ati from the working machine and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I did a fresh install of Ubuntu some months ago, I am unfortunately not able to check this answer to be correct and give you full credit.